# How can I access the promise result from outside of the promise body

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise function for example `getName(code)` so we have:

```
getName(code)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

We want to define a function to return the result name to it and do something with it.

How can we relate the defined function and method call?

For example:

```
async function name(code) {
  getName(code)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
  return ???
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  let x = name(i);
  // Do something with x, for example:
  alert(x);
}
```

P.S: I know that the result is accessible inside `.then` body, but I want to access it inside the `name` function scope and return it from the function.

Comment: You can't return it from the function. The value is available only in the future. The best you'll get will be returning a promise for it (by just putting the `return` in front of the promise chain), but on the `name(i)` call you will always need to wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
async function name(code) {
    try {
        const name = await getName(code);
        // Do something here
        return name;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('[ERROR]', e);
    }
}
```

Remember, In-order to use `await`, the code should be enclosed within an `async` function.

Comment: In this case the `name` variable will contain the promise data, doesn't it?

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji Yes it will. I have improved the answer to catch errors btw.

Comment: Keep in mind that ***this still does not return `name` from the function***.  It returns a promise whose eventual resolved value is `name`.  All `async` functions return a promise.  The caller of this function still must use `await` or `.then()` to retrieve the value.  I don't think this actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: What do you suggest @jfriend00 ?

Comment: @Vishnudev - I posted an answer with my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I was asked what I would suggest.

You have an asynchronous result.  That means your function returns long before the asynchronous result is available.   Therefore, you cannot return the asynchronous result directly.

The usual two options for communicating back an asynchronous result are a callback or returning a promise.  In either case, the caller of the function has to use the asynchronous result in the specific manner in which it's returned, not as a direct return value.

In your case, you are already using promises so what makes sense is to just return the promise you already have:

```
function name() {
    return getName(code).then(...);
}
```

There is no advantage to using an `async` function here or `await` as you just have a single asynchronous operation that's already got a promise.  Just return that promise.  We don't put a `.catch()` handler here because there's no specific error processing required at this level - we want the rejected promise to be seen by the caller as is.

Then, to use this function which returns a promise, you can either use `.then()` on it:

```
name().then(result => {
    // use the result in here
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

or you can use `await`:

```
async function someOtherFunc() {
    try {
        let result = await name();
        // do something with result here
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

> I know that the result is accessible inside .then body, but I want to access it inside the name function scope and return it from the function.

You can't access it outside the `.then()` handler and you can't return it directly from the function.  That's a limitation of asynchronous operations in Javascript.  The function itself returns BEFORE the asynchronous callback has even been called so the asynchronous result isn't available at the time the function returns.  This is what promises are for.  You return the promise and you set it up so the asynchronous result is the resolved value of the promise.  The caller then uses that returned promise to register an interest in the eventual resolved value (or reject error).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clearing things up. The second method you have written is exactly what I intended and obviously the access of variable outside of the .then is not possible.

Comment: @Vishnudev - Yeah, I saw you asking me what I suggested and thought you were the OP.  OK, not sure the OP will even see this.